How do I add rows to a JTable with an exterior method
I'm making a setup mode for a digital hallpass so admin can access student names and student IDs. My code is supposed to have a JTable with student names and IDs, and when you press the Add Row button, it adds a blank row to the JTable by removing it, creating a new Object[][], then reassinging it to the JTable before adding it. But instead of getting a new blank row, my JTable doesn't change, no matter how many times I press the button
I tried creating a static method that created an Object[][] to reassign the JTable, but the new row in the Object[][] has not been reflected in the JTable.
This is my code
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
public class studentDataBase extends GoldenGate {
    private static Object[][] buddy = t.getDb();
    private static JTable ourTable;
    studentDataBase() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        Object[] columns = {"Names", "IDs"};
        ourTable = new JTable(buddy, columns);
        JLabel isThis = new JLabel("Is this working?");
        JButton addRow = new JButton("Add New Student");
        addRow.setBounds(400, 450, 200, 20);
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                window.remove(ourTable);
                buddy = addNewRow(ourTable);
                ourTable = new JTable(buddy, columns);
                window.add(ourTable);
            }
        });
        window.add(addRow);
        window.setSize(720, 700);
        isThis.setBounds(400, 200, 200, 30);
        ourTable.setBounds(400, 400, 300, 300);
        window.add(ourTable);
        window.add(isThis);
        window.add(new JScrollPane(ourTable));
        window.pack();
        window.setLayout(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }
    public static Object[][] addNewRow(JTable tab) {
        Object[][] update = new Object[tab.getModel().getRowCount()+1][tab.getModel().getColumnCount()];
        for(int r = 0; r < tab.getModel().getRowCount(); r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < tab.getModel().getColumnCount(); c++) {
                update[r][c] = tab.getModel().getValueAt(r, c);
            }
        }
        return update;
    }
}



Why would you recreate the entire table to add a new row? Simply use the addRow(...) method of the DefaultTableModel to add an empty row.

@camickr the code in the question uses this constructor to create a JTable. Looking at the source code for that constructor, I see that it creates a subclass of AbstractTableModel and not a DefaultTableModel.

How to Use Tables


Create a DefaultTableModel 2) Create the JTable using the DefaultTableModel 3) Use the addRow(...) method of the DefaultTableModel to add an empty row.


A JTable, like most Swing components, is just a view of data that comes from a separate data source, known as a model.  A JTable’s data comes from its TableModel.  To add a row, you should not create a brand new JTable;  just alter the model, and the JTable will notice that modification and will update its own display accordingly.
The top part of the TableModel documentation page contains this:

All Known Implementing Classes:
AbstractTableModel, DefaultTableModel

You should create a single DefaultTableModel (only once!), and use its addRow method.  (Advanced Swing developers should extend AbstractTableModel, but that is out of scope here.)
Also, never do setLayout(null).  It will undermine the behavior of your table and your scrollpane.  The sizes of components are complicated, because the size of text is complicated:  A “12 point” font is a font in which a line of text takes up ¹²⁄₇₂ of an inch.  The exact number of pixels needed to do that will depend on the monitor in use and the graphics mode in use.  All of that complicated computation is already done by Swing components, and standard layout managers will properly accommodate those computed sizes.  The default layout of a JFrame is a BorderLayout, so you don’t have to do anything to make use of a standard layout manager;  it’s already there.
Because layout managers handle placing and sizing components, you can remove all calls to setBounds, once you remove setLayout(null).
So, with a DefaultTableModel, and proper layout manager use, your class might look something like this:
public class studentDataBase extends GoldenGate {

    private final DefaultTableModel buddy;
    private final JTable ourTable;

    studentDataBase() {
        Object[] columns = {"Names", "IDs"};
        buddy = new DefaultTableModel(t.getDb(), columns);

        ourTable = new JTable(buddy);

        JLabel isThis = new JLabel("Is this working?");

        JButton addRow = new JButton("Add New Student");
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                buddy.addRow(new Object[columns.length]);
            }
        });

        Box addRowContainer = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        addRowContainer.add(addRow);

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.add(addRowContainer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        window.add(isThis, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(new JScrollPane(ourTable), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.pack();

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        window.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}

